# Invalid object name when inputting data from .aspx into sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

This is my error

```
Invalid object name 'userdatabase'
```

This is the code for the source error

```
enter code here
Line 27: 
Line 28:             User.Open();
Line 29:             xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 30:             User.Close();
Line 31:
```

this is the stack trace

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'userdatabase'.]

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean       breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789270

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340622

System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244

System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +275

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +208

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
   Default2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Calum Barnett\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite3\Default2.aspx.cs:29

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9614758

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10

System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13

System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35

System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
`
```

And this is the cs code:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            Label1.Text = ("**Registration Succesful");
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection User = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TOSHIBA0007\\TESTSERVER;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into userdatabase(Username, Email,  Password)Values(@Username, @Email, @Password)", User);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", InputUsername.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", InputEmail.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", InputPassword.Text);

            User.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            User.Close();

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                InputUsername.Text = "";
                InputPassword.Text = "";
                InputEmail.Text = "";
                VerifyPassword.Text = "";

            }    
        }            
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated as i am a beginner to these kinds of errors.

Comment: Do you actually have such a table?

Comment: You're not setting the default database ("initial catalog") in your connection string.

Comment: Oh thats didnt mean to mess that

Comment: "userdatabase"? sounds like database name instead of table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be wrong table name userdatabase or mismatch in table name...

```
SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into userdatabase(Username, Email,
    Password)Values(@Username, @Email, @Password)", User);
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", InputUsername.Text);
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", InputEmail.Text);
                xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", InputPassword.Text);
```